# th:each indexing throwing errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having issues indexing my for each objects. I have a list that I pull from the repository, that is called MonthlyAcct. I want to iterate over the list in the thymeleaf html file and show each property of the MonthlyAcct object displayed as an editable input field inside a table. I keep getting errors that Indexing into type 'monthAcct' is not supported, or currently, the error is: "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'monthAcct[0]' available as request attribute."
This is definitely an issue with how I've set up th:field, as if I switch it out to th:name, it shows up and does not throw errors. Do I have to make this into a form to get the th:field to work?
I have used this same style/tactic in other areas of my project and it works, so I am not sure why this time this type of set up is not working. Any ideas? I also have a different form on this page, that updates details for a client class, can this be causing any issues?

Just for reference I have tried * and $ with the th:each statement, and have tried both symbols with the th:field as well. Both throw the above mentioned  error.

```html
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-search="true"  data-show-columns="true" >
    <thead>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>January</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="acct, stat : ${monthAcct}">
            <td th:text="${acct.year}"></td>
            <td>
            <input type="number" class="text-left form-control"  th:field="${monthAcct[__${stat.index}__].janAmt}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/accounting/client/{id}")
public String accountingDetails(@PathVariable("id")Client client, MonthlyAccountingTracker monthlyAccountingTracker, Model model) {
    List<MonthlyAccountingTracker>  monthAcct = monthlyAccountingTrackerRepository.findByClient(client);
    model.addAttribute("client",clientRepository.findById(client.getId()));
    model.addAttribute("monthAcct",monthAcct);
    return "accounting";
}
```

```html
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name="MonthlyMinAcctTracker")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MonthlyAccountingTracker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="client")
    private Client client;
    private BigDecimal year;
    private BigDecimal janAmt;
    
     public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public BigDecimal getJanAmt() {
        return janAmt;
    }

    public void setJanAmt(BigDecimal janAmt) {
        this.janAmt = janAmt;
    }
}
```

I get my monthAcct list from the repository:

```html
public interface MonthlyAccountingTrackerRepository extends CrudRepository<MonthlyAccountingTracker,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    MonthlyAccountingTracker save(MonthlyAccountingTracker entity);

    MonthlyAccountingTracker findById(Long id);

    List<MonthlyAccountingTracker> findByClient(Client client);

    void delete(MonthlyAccountingTracker entity);

    List<MonthlyAccountingTracker> findAll();
}
```

Comment: `*{monthAcct}` must be `${monthAcct}`

Comment: can you please add the code for your `MonthlyAccountingTracker` class

Comment: @rieckpil I've added it. The code populates if using th:name, so th:field is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

*{monthAcct} should be ${monthAcct} as you are setting the value in modelAndView or in your case model. The monthAcct is not a field of the th:object.

Comment: Still not working. I changed just the monthAcct in the th:each, and then both there and in the th:field area, and its still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a List as a form backing object.  You need another object that wraps your array (and to use that object as your backing object).  For example:

Java:

```
// Backing object
class BackingObject {
  List<MonthlyAccountingTracker> accounts;

  public BackingObject(List<MonthlyAccountingTracker> accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
  }

  // Put in getters/setters...
}

// Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/accounting/client/{id}")
public String accountingDetails(@PathVariable("id")Client client, MonthlyAccountingTracker monthlyAccountingTracker, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("client",clientRepository.findById(client.getId()));
  model.addAttribute("form", new BackingObject(monthlyAccountingTrackerRepository.findByClient(client)));
  return "accounting";
}
```

Form:

```
<form th:object="${form}">
  .
  .
  .

  <tr th:each="acct, stat : *{accounts}">
      <td th:text="${acct.year}"></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="text-left form-control"  th:field="*{accounts[__${stat.index}__].janAmt}"/>
      </td>
  </tr>

  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `*` instead of `$` sign for `monthAcct` field:

```
<input type="number" class="text-left form-control"  th:field="*{monthAcct[__${stat.index}__].janAmt}"/>
```