# spring mvc thymeleaf form update array of objects

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to create a thymeleaf template with a single form for editing multiple items.  In this example, the items are Todo objects.

```
public class Todo {
    private int id;
    private String desc;
    private boolean done;
}
```

Based on some googling, my broken solution is below:

```
<form>

<div th:each="todo, iter: *{todos}">
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{todos[__${iter.index}__].id}" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{todos[__${iter.index}__].desc}"/>
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{todos[__${iter.index}__].done}" th:checked="${todo.done}"/>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="update" value="upate"  
formmethod="post" 
formaction="/todos/update-multiple"
class="btn btn-danger"/>

<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" 
formmethod="get" 
formaction="/todos"  
class="btn btn-secondary"/> 
</form>
```

Here's the controller

```
@PostMapping("/todos/update-multiple-form")
public String updateMultipleForm(@RequestParam List<Integer> ids, Model model){
  List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>();
  ids.forEach(id->todos.add(service.get(id)));
  model.addAttribute("todos", todos);
  return "update-multiple";
}

@PostMapping("/todos/update-multiple")
public String updateMultiple(@RequestParam List<Todo> todos, Model model){
  todos.forEach(service::update);
  return "redirect:/todos";
}
```

Here's the error message:

````
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'todos[0]' available as request attribute```


Google around but couldn't find an example on using a single form to update multiple objects.
````

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652095/theach-indexing-throwing-errors/59652657#59652657

Comment: Thanks, Metroids.  Using a backing class works. It would be nice without creating another class but I guess this will do.

Comment: There's a tutorial on this:  https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list